# Cannot set duration for one image while converting images to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I can't set duration for single image in the video. There are 24 images from here:
`http://luna1.diviner.ucla.edu/~jpierre/diviner/level4_polar/hourly_maps/south/polar_south_80_summer_tbol-hour"` named in for each `%02d.png` (concat this to get links). I use code

```
ffmpeg -i e:\gals\moon\polar_south_80_summer_tbol-hour%02d.png -t 0.2 -r 5 -vcodec mpeg4 e:/test.mp4
```

and always get 1 second video, but I need to have 0.2 seconds for each image, hence the whole video should be 4.8s. Someone in different threat say I need to set -framerate 5, to get 0.2s for each image, but this doesn't work. I use many variants of parameters: -d 4.8 -r 5, or -t 4.8 -r 5, or -r 24, and always get 1s of the whole video. Setting -loop 1 gets desired lenght, but it loops many times wrongly framed images.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Found solution thanks to this accepted answer: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23530/use-ffmpeg-to-create-a-video-from-a-few-images/23532#23532?newreg=9725fccd8ad74a73bf82ca6773cd5a78 after 2hrs of searching! It's clearly translated that `-framerate 1/0.2` gives 0.2s per image, and `-r 24` gives the video overall framerate. A bit messy, but works.